# How many have voted?

Tags: discussion, election

I understand SE would probably prefer not to have a running counter to show the standings in the election.

The question for me is "How many people have voted?"

Is that something that's sharable with us? For a board that has good activity, I was hoping to see more nominations, and good voting activity.

Answer (score 5):

Is the banner on the bottom of the election page visible to you?

As of 5:47PM PDT 2014-04-02

[image]

Comment: Nope. You are a mod now, right? I think us regular folk can't see that. 116 voted? That's pretty good. Thanks.

Comment: Uh oh.  I hope it is okay I shared that.  Oh well.

Comment: Well, there are just over 1100 eligible voters (rep over 150) and I'm sure more than half haven't visited in a few weeks at least. So I'm thinking 600 would be a good turnout.

Comment: I also thought everyone could see those numbers.  You just beat me to posting. :)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I very much doubt we will get there, based on other sites elections.

Comment: What are the stats looking like now?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money